# Received memory errors xcode PhoneGap app?

Tags: cordova, ios7

I am using PhoneGap to create an application. The first page loads a lots of images via ajax. However, each image load shows a memory warning in xcode debugger and after 5-6 such warnings the app crashes and xcode debugger says app had closed due to memory error. Has anyone had the same problem? Please help me out.

I have also noticed that loading local images gives no memory errors at all, irrespective of the sizes of the images I use. I am using the  tag to show images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help to post some code that we can see before one can figure out what's wrong...